# Why I get "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation" while looping groups users

Tags: permissions, groups, logging, user-accounts

Could anyone explain me why when I trying to loop user of a group 
`foreach (var u in group.Users){....}`,
I get the error :

> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

I notice that inside `group.User.Count` I have this exception:

> group.Users.Count' threw an `exception of type
>
> 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'  int
>   {System.UnauthorizedAccessException}`

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
                                                delegate()
                                                {
                                                    using (SPSite scsite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
                                                    {
                                                        using (SPWeb scweb = scsite.OpenWeb())
                                                        {
                                                            foreach (var g in SPContext.Current.Web.Roles.Web.Groups)
                                                            {
                                                                SPGroup group = (SPGroup)g;
                                                                if (group.Name.ToLower().Contains("proprietari"))
                                                                {

                                                                    foreach (var u in group.Users)
                                                                    {
                                                                        SPUser user = (SPUser)u;
                                                                        if (user.Name.Equals(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name))
                                                                        {
                                                                            a = true;
                                                                        }
                                                                    }

                                                                }
                                                            }


                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });
```

Comment: If you want to check if the user exists in Group or not, you can simply use [SPGroup.ContainsCurrentUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroup.containscurrentuser.aspx)

Comment: Does the user you're running this code as have permission?

Comment: Thanks so much! But, can you see in my code , why I can't loop group.user if I'm executing inside "RunWithElevatedPrivileges()"  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use SPContext within a "RunWithElevatedPrivileges" block, but objects you get from "SPContext" such as: SPUser, SPWeb, etc. are not running in elevated privilege, they just take the current user security context.

- So why not just use "scweb" to get to the "Group". Since "scweb" object is initialized within the "RunWithElevatedPrivileges" block just try this instead:

  ```
  foreach (var g in scweb.Groups)
  {
   // ...
  }
  ```

Comment: This solution does not work! I'm doing the same as you proposed, but get also unauthorized message. Any different approach?